# How to setup Plone sites working only with OpenID

Tags: openid, plone

I have a Plone 4.1 site using the OpenId module. When a user clicks on login it opens the dialog to login using OpenId but also using classic login/password. I wan't a site using only OpenId. Is there an easy way to config a site to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to disable the http basic auth:

1. Go to the acl_users in your plone site via the Zope Management Interface.
2. Click on 'plugins'. You should now see a list of Plugin Types (eg. Challenge Plugins, Extraction Plugins, etc).
3. Click on Extraction Plugins.
4. Deactivate normal plugins: Move all Active Plugins (potentially: credentials_cookie_auth, credentials_basic_auth) to "Available Plugins" so that only openid + session is left. You will need the to avoid that the user is challenged every request.

Now only OpenID should be the available authentication method. If you need the rest again, simply activate them in "Extraction Plugins".

**Be aware** that you need to have a fall back manager user in order to make further changes with elevated privileges. Either by being able to login via the Zope root, which I expect or by assigning yourself the System Administrator role to your own Open ID login. **Otherwise you may lock yourself out**.